# Subset rows based on values in a specific column

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, data.table

I want to retrieve the rows where the `Distance` column has a value between -50,000 and 50,000.

```
library(data.table)
all.correlated <- setDT(all.correlated)[, .SD[abs(.N) >= 50000], by = Distance]
```

Traceback:

```
Empty data.table (0 rows and 7 cols): Distance,Probe,GeneID,Symbol,Sides,Raw.p...
```

Input:

```
all.correlated <- structure(list(Probe = c("cg24800175", "cg08036309", "cg21411366", 
"cg25449950", "cg02155398", "cg03714619"), GeneID = c("ENSG00000179115", 
"ENSG00000002549", "ENSG00000002549", "ENSG00000002549", "ENSG00000171132", 
"ENSG00000171132"), Symbol = c("FARSA", "LAP3", "LAP3", "LAP3", 
"PRKCE", "PRKCE"), Distance = c(-3007, 4041822, -7187580, -7187578, 
717992, 718037), Sides = c("L10", "R10", "L9", "L9", "R1", "R1"
), Raw.p = c(3.89552514236314e-08, 5.19302181010518e-08, 5.19302181010518e-08, 
5.19302181010518e-08, 1.27186058587196e-07, 1.27186058587196e-07
), FDR = c(3.79438408118467e-06, 3.79438408118467e-06, 3.79438408118467e-06, 
3.79438408118467e-06, 3.79438408118467e-06, 3.79438408118467e-06
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2afcd1808260>)
```

Comment: `all.correlated[abs(Distance) <= 50000]` or `all.correlated[Distance %between% c(-50000, 50000)]` or `all.correlated[between(Distance, -50000, 50000)]`

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
filter(all.correlated, between(Distance, -50000, 50000))
```

or base R:

```
all.correlated[between(all.correlated$Distance, -50000, 50000), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering is done in the `i` slot of `data.table` (cf. [`` ?`[.data.table` ``](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.8.0/topics/data.table))
, i.e.:

```r
all.correlated[between(Distance, -50000, 50000)]
```

Your code has a couple of issues:

```r
all.correlated[, .SD[abs(.N) >= 50000], by = Distance]
```

1. `.N`: this returns the number of rows per group:

   ```r
   all.correlated[, .N, by = Distance]
   #    Distance     N
   #       <num> <int>
   # 1:    -3007     1
   # 2:  4041822     1
   # 3: -7187580     1
   # 4: -7187578     1
   # 5:   717992     1
   # 6:   718037     1
   ```

   So you are basically asking to return all *absolute counts* larger than `50000`
2. `.SD`: From the help file `?.SD`:

   > - ‘.SD’ is a ‘data.table’ containing the *S*ubset of ‘x’'s
   >   *D*ata for each group, excluding any columns used in ‘by’ (or
   >   ‘keyby’).

   Thus, you are requesting the subset for each group, which are then row binded again, compare `all.correlated[, .SD, by = Distance]` with `all_correlated` and you will see that all that changes is the order, with the group column being now in teh first position.
3. Overall your code translates to:

   1. By `Distance` count the number of observations
   2. Return all rows, where the (absolute) number of observations is larger than `50000`

Answer (score 0):

Using `[`

```
library(data.table)

all.correlated[Distance >= -50000 & Distance <= 50000,]
        Probe          GeneID Symbol Distance Sides        Raw.p          FDR
1: cg24800175 ENSG00000179115  FARSA    -3007   L10 3.895525e-08 3.794384e-06
```

or `subset`

```
library(data.table)

subset(all.correlated, Distance >= -50000 & Distance <= 50000)
        Probe          GeneID Symbol Distance Sides        Raw.p          FDR
1: cg24800175 ENSG00000179115  FARSA    -3007   L10 3.895525e-08 3.794384e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to reproduce your data, but you could use filter() from the dplyr package. So

> your_dataframe <- your_dataframe %>%
> filter( between(Distance, -50000, 50000) )